# putting non executable project into container docker

Tags: docker

I have a general question about docker, let's say I have 2 projects, 1 of them is a spring boot application, the other one is a non executable project, it contains a lots of shared methods and stuff where some other project are referencing it and some config file, if I want to put my project inside docker and run it inside docker, what should I do, because the second project is a non executable project, so then I won't be able to do docker run, but the other project will work only if it can access the non executable project

Comment: Docker is trying to give you a runtime environment for your application so I believe it won't work. But incase you still want to share an image which contains your non executable source then you might consider to use multiple image in 1 Dockerfile, and then copy non executable source into some where in new Docker image then your first project can use it.

Comment: Emmm how do I copy the non executable source? Do I package it as a jar, then do a copy? If so, what should the command look like

Comment: How exactly does the first project need to access the second?  (Is it just a collection of static assets that get opened as files?  Do you expect there to be an HTTP service?)

Comment: Basically it will not work without the second project, it uses a lots of method inside that, for example database communication methods,

Comment: Not like access, it’s like basically a shared project where many other project relies on it, in this case, what is the best option.

Comment: I do not think you need a second docker container for that just to manage config file, second thing if start container with http server you can access volume of second container untill you shared same space between these two container. BTW you do not need  always executable to keep up and running your second container you can achive that but the question is again about accessing space of other container?

Comment: @TaojieChen, I will write an answer soon but during that time you can take a look at this. https://blog.alexellis.io/mutli-stage-docker-builds/. It's the same as you said, package non executable project as a jar, copy it into your executable project image. So how we can achieve this: Stage 1: Build your non executable project to a jar file. Stage 2. Copy it into your main stage, which will be used to run your executable project.

Comment: Could you please add all things you've done with Docker stuff?

Comment: Sorry I can’t do that, but I will take a look